# После парсинга сайт недоступен

Tags: python, парсер

Пишу парсинг html страницы на python, после нескольких запросов не доступен сайт - попросту не открывается (захожу через прокси - всё работает). Вопрос - необходимо ли прописывать в response что либо, для того чтобы сервер не определял меня как "злостного парсера"? ))

Comment: Сайты блокируют доступ обычно после многочисленных запросов, тогда использование прокси может помочь. А какой сайт вы парсите, если не секрет? :)

Comment: Может сначала по самому сайту побродить? Вдруг там есть что-то типа "политики для ботов", или вообще - какое API или нужные RSS-потоки обнаружатся...

Comment: gil9red, http://www.shopindia.ru - этот сайт. Даже не понимаю почему так всё, т.к. не делаю сотню запросов за раз

Comment: Вероятно, это бан. Чтобы сервер не определял вас как злостного парсера, переставайте им быть. )

Comment: Nick Volynkin, ну уж нет ))). Я сделал всего навсего < 10 запросов. Как то странно всё

Comment: Дело может быть не в количестве запросов, а в их частоте. Плюс один IP, плюс UserAgent - вот и бан.

Comment: @Ruben это даже не админы сайта банят и не движок сайта, а хостер временно блокирует доступ с вашего ip, так как вы грубо говоря досите сайт. Пробегитесь по своему исходному коду, возможно он очень часто обращается к сайту. У меня стоит парсер объявлений, парсит раз в 30 секунд, слава Богу пока что не банили)) Хотя на первых парах я юзал рандомно прокси.